# Get the latest npm package version programatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, version

Looking for a way to access the latest version number of an npm package. Is there some kind of API where I can't ping npm directly? Or is there a programatic npm command I can use?

```
getNpmVersion('lodash').then(console.log) // => 4.11.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Found a module called `npm-latest` that does exactly this:

```
import npmLatest from 'npm-latest'
import Promise from 'bluebird'
const npmLatestAsync = Promise.promisify(npmLatest)
async function getNpmVersion (dep) {
  let { name, version } = await npmLatestAsync(dep)
  return { name, version}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Also:

`npm view {packagename} version`